# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath' GoogleIAP

Tags: android, android-studio

Trying to run android app getting following error

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.congle7997:GoogleIAP:1.0.8.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {  url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Any help much appreiciated

Comment: Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/congle7997/GoogleIAP/1.0.8/GoogleIAP-1.0.8.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

Answer (score 0):

Because the library was in Private mode at that time, you could not use it, now it has been set to Public again so you can use it normally.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).